# AngularFire listen for child added

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

what i would like to do is just listening on child_added event to receive ONLY the single last child.
The idea is to start an angular application (appA), create the ref to the list and then wait.

From an other application (appB), i can add an item in that list.

I want the appB reacts one time to with that item added by the appB

```
this.itemsRef = this.db.list('gpsAlerts');

this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges(['child_added'])
  .subscribe(actions => {
    actions.forEach(action => {
      console.log(action.type);
      console.log(action.key);
      console.log(action.payload.val());
    });
  });
```

But i already received every items in my list at the launch of the appA.
And also, when i add item from appB, the method is called multiple times.
I expect to get just the last item once.

Any idea of i can do that ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Since you're subscribing to `snapshotChanges`, if you don't want it to be called multiple times, you can use [RxJS `debounceTime()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html).

So in your case it will look like:

```
...
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
...

this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges(['child_added'])
  .debounceTime(500)
  .subscribe(actions => {
    actions.forEach(action => {
      console.log(action.type);
      console.log(action.key);
      console.log(action.payload.val());
    });
  });
```

Then the scope of `subscribe` will only be interpreted 500ms after the last call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i still have the same behaviour :-(